# Mac Mini mid 2010 drive identification

Tags: mac-mini

I have a mid 2010 Mac Mini with 2 drives.  I need to replace 1 of them.  How do I tell physically which drive is the second drive?  With the case upside down which drive (0 or 1) is on top?

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Please indicate the exact model of Mac nini you own. The Mac mini Server (mid-2010) came equipped with 2 hard drives, with an optional SuperDrive optical drive. This [iFixit page](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/191106/Mac+mini+server+Mid+2010+HD+replace) on replacing internal HD drives in the server model may help you determine which is which. IMHO, if you're going to crack open a Mini - a complex process - replace both drives with SSDs while you have the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After removing both internal drive I determined that the second hdd is underneath.  So everything has to be removed to get to it.  This includes fan, system board, power supply and brackets.  A very good detailed instructions can be found at https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+Mini+Mid+2010+Dual+Hard+Drive/8958.

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea of the construction of a Mini, but you could test it empirically.

Remove one drive, see if it will boot.
If yes, look at Disk Utility & see which drive remains.
If no, then you removed the only boot source.

Comment: The process of removing the second drive is non-trivial.  I am looking to avoid removing it if I do not have to.